# Optimization level affecting template overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, linker, compiler-optimization

I have run into interesting behavior regarding template overload resolution where it differed between release and debug build. I'd like to be able to understand the rules used by the compiler/linker that make it behave this way.
I've tried digging a bit and this is what I have come up with:

**S.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
enum class Enumeration : uint32_t {
    A = 0,
    B
};
struct S {
    template<typename T>
    bool func(Enumeration en) {
        std::cout << "enum nonspec\n";
        return func<T>(static_cast<uint32_t>(en));
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool func(uint32_t en) {
        std::cout << "uint32_t nonspec\n";
        return func<T>(en);
    }
};
```

**S.cpp**

```
#include "S.h"
template<>
bool S::func<float>(uint32_t en) {
    std::cout << "float specialization\n";
    return en;
}

template<>
bool S::func<uint32_t>(uint32_t en) {
    std::cout << "uint32_t specialization\n";
    return en - 1;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "S.h"

int main() {
    S s;
    Enumeration a = Enumeration::B;
    s.func<float>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried compiling the respective compilation units (S.cpp.o, main.cpp.o, and the resulting binary).
I found out that the result depends completely on the optimization level of the compilation of main.cpp.o.

With `-O0` the output is 
`enum nonspec`
`float specialization`.

With `-O1` the output is
`enum nonspec`
`uint32_t nonspec`
`uint32_t nonspec`
`float specialization`.

With `-O2` or `-O3` the output is 
`enum nonspec`
and then infinite recursion `uint32_t nonspec`.

I've inspected the object file and `-O0` has 
`0000000000000000 W bool S::func<float>(Enumeration)`
`0000000000000000 W bool S::func<float>(unsigned int)`,
`-O1` only has 
`0000000000000000 W bool S::func<float>(unsigned int)`,
and `-O3` has neither symbol.

Compiler used: gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
Linker used: ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.3) 2.27

I think I understand what happens, but I'd like to know if there are any rules this behavior is based on.

Comment: Your specialization (declaration) is not visible from its usage -> ill-formed NDR.

Comment: And then reasoning about UB, ill-formed program is pointless.

Comment: Yes, seems to works is a possible output of UB, IFNDR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ Standard requires all template specializations to be declared *before* they are used.

See [[temp.expl.spec]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp#expl.spec-6):

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared **before** the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, **in every translation unit** in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.
>
> If the program does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and either the specialization is used in a way that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place or the member is a virtual member function, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

So the program is ill-formed, NDR. The compiler is not required to issue an error or warning, and there are no restrictions on what happens in this case, since it should never happen. So whether it "works", "appears to work" or "doesn't work" is pure accident.

What probably happens is that with optimizations on the compiler inlines the calls, and otherwise doesn't, which allows the linker to still find the specialization at link time.